# Union of Generic List does not work the way I expect it

Tags: python, generics, types, type-hinting

So I have a function that takes either a list of objs or a single obj and returns a list.

Here is what it looks like:

```python
from typing import Union, List, TypeVar, Type

T = TypeVar('T')


def to_list(obj_type: Type[T], obj_or_list: Union[List[T], T]) -> List[T]:
    ...
```

This works fine if I pass a str in.
e.g.

```python
result: List[str] = to_list(str, "hi")
```

but fails (type checking error via pyright) when I pass in a list of str (or a list of any objects)
e.g.

```
input_data: List[str] = ["hi"]
result: List[str] = to_list(str,input_data)
```

Here is the error message

> Expression of type "List[str | List[str]]" cannot be assigned to declared type "List[str]"

Looks the type checker (pyright) is thinking that `to_list` is returning `List[Union[List[str],str]]` instead of just `List[str]`.

Basically instead of interpreting `T` as `str`, it interpreted `T` as `Union[List[str], str]`
which is kinda annoying cause I assumed that it would be smart enough to determine that T is str because I explicitly passed `str` as the `obj_type`.

My two questions are:

- is there a way to achieve what I want? basically a function that takes either a list of objects or a single object and returns a list of objects (while keeping the type hints)
  My current work-around is this

```python
from typing import Union, List, TypeVar, Type

T = TypeVar('T')


def to_list(obj_type: Type[T], obj_or_list: Any) -> List[T]:
    ...
```

- Is there a technical name for determining how the generic parameter is resolved? So I can search up on and learn about it?

  - e.g. Basically, if I pass in `List[str]` to a parameter with the type `Union[List[T],T]`, then there are two possibilities:

    - `T` is `List[str]`
    - `T` is `str`,
  - What I want to know is if there is a specific/academic/technical name for the process of determining what `T` is

Comment: I have copy-pasted your code and run it, works fine, didn't get any errors.
What version of python do you use? I've tested with 3.7

Comment: Its not a real error. Its just a type checking error. I used vscode with pylance and python extensions

Answer (score 0):

- **Partial answer** to my second question:
  The technical name for this process is known as TypeVar matching (sometimes also called TypeVar "solving").  relevant link: https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/910#issuecomment-667553334